# Не получается авторизоваться на сайте с использованием cUrl

Tags: php, post, curl

Здравствуйте Уважаемые! 
Имеется такой код:

```
header('Content-type: text/html;; charset=utf-8');
require_once 'phpQuery.php';

function login($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt","w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login);
}
function grab_page($site){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);
}

    $html = grab_page("https://wap.moneysyst.biz/p-auths.php");
    $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($html);
    $user = $doc->find('.login tr:eq(2) td:eq(0) input:eq(1)')->attr('value');

    $data_post = "userlogin=avtoreginfo&userpass=avtoregfm&go=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8&user=$user";

    $page = login("https://wap.moneysyst.biz/p-auths.php",$data_post);

    echo $page;
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, данный код должен авторизовываться на сайте и выдавать контент, который отображается только после авторизации, но авторизация не проходит, просто выкидывает.

Логин и пароль верные, кукисы сохраняет в файл.
В начале код получает html код страницы с формой авторизации и получает уникальное значение со скрытой формы user, данное значение получается в переменную $user, далее происходит отправка post запроса на авторизацию.

Поправьте мой код если конечно в нём есть ошибки. Допускаю то, что сам сайт блокирует подобную авторизацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Замените конец каждой вашей функции и посмотрите, что выводится.
Лично у меня код показал

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: ААААаааа... понял, упустил, точно, не обратил внимание, что сайт https. Благодарю! Сейчас буду пробовать снова.

Comment: добавил эти две строки:  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); но все равно не работает авторизация